# pasting multiple list elements to create single character string

Tags: r, list, paste

I currently have a clunky solution that for pasting together pieces of text and list elements to form a single string. Some white spaces are necessary to stay in, and others must be removed.

My code currently does produce the desired outcome:

"Text 1 has spaces (x+60)*(x+60)-(y+30)*(y+30)-(z-20)*(z-20) Text2 has spaces a1Text3"

But it otherwise isn't that eloquent, and I was wondering if there were better ways of reaching the same outcome?

```
x <- seq(-60,60, length.out = 5)
y <- seq(-30,10, length.out = 5)
z <- seq(20,60, length.out = 5)

area <- c("a1","a2","a3","a4", "a5")

newlist <- list(x,y,z,area)

Text1 <- "Text 1 has spaces"
Text2 <- "Text2 has spaces"
Text3 <- "Text3"

formula <- paste("(x-", newlist[[1]],")*","(x-", newlist[[1]],")", "-",
                 "(y-", newlist[[2]],")*","(y-", newlist[[2]],")","-",
                 "(z-", newlist[[3]],")*","(z-", newlist[[3]],")")

formula <- gsub(" ", "", formula)
formula <- gsub("--", "+", formula)

newname <- paste(newlist[[4]],Text3)
newname <- gsub(" ", "", newname) 

result <- paste(Text1,formula,Text2,newname)
result
```

> ```
> [1] "Text 1 has spaces (x+60)*(x+60)-(y+30)*(y+30)-(z-20)*(z-20) Text2 has spaces a1Text3"
>
> [2] "Text 1 has spaces (x+30)*(x+30)-(y+20)*(y+20)-(z-30)*(z-30) Text2 has spaces a2Text3"
>
> [3] "Text 1 has spaces (x-0)*(x-0)-(y+10)*(y+10)-(z-40)*(z-40) Text2 has spaces a3Text3"  
>
> [4] "Text 1 has spaces (x-30)*(x-30)-(y-0)*(y-0)-(z-50)*(z-50) Text2 has spaces a4Text3"  
>
> [5] "Text 1 has spaces (x-60)*(x-60)-(y-10)*(y-10)-(z-60)*(z-60) Text2 has spaces a5Text3"
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eliminate a few lines by putting everything in `paste0` and then `gsub`bing once:

```r
lis <- list(x = seq(-60,60, length.out = 5),
            y = seq(-30,10, length.out = 5),
            z = seq(20,60, length.out = 5),
            area = c("a1","a2","a3","a4", "a5"))

result <- paste0("Text1 has spaces (x-", lis[[1]], ")*(x-", lis[[1]],
                 ")-(y-", lis[[2]], ")*", "(y-", lis[[2]], ")-(z-", lis[[3]], 
                 ")*(z-", lis[[3]], ") Text2 has spaces ", lis[[4]], "Text3"
              )
result <- gsub("--", "+", result)

#### OUTPUT ####

[1] "Text1 has spaces (x+60)*(x+60)-(y+30)*(y+30)-(z-20)*(z-20) Text2 has spaces a1Text3"
[2] "Text1 has spaces (x+30)*(x+30)-(y+20)*(y+20)-(z-30)*(z-30) Text2 has spaces a2Text3"
[3] "Text1 has spaces (x-0)*(x-0)-(y+10)*(y+10)-(z-40)*(z-40) Text2 has spaces a3Text3"  
[4] "Text1 has spaces (x-30)*(x-30)-(y-0)*(y-0)-(z-50)*(z-50) Text2 has spaces a4Text3"  
[5] "Text1 has spaces (x-60)*(x-60)-(y-10)*(y-10)-(z-60)*(z-60) Text2 has spaces a5Text3"
```

Alternatively, you can also play around with the `glue` package:

```r
library(glue)

result <- glue("Text1 has spaces (x-{lis[[1]]})*(x-{lis[[1]]})-(y-{lis[[2]]})*",
               "(y-{lis[[2]]})-(z-{lis[[3]]})*(z-{lis[[3]]}) Text2 has spaces ",
               "{lis[[4]]}Text3",
              )
result <- gsub("--", "+", result)

#### OUTPUT ####

Text1 has spaces (x+60)*(x+60)-(y+30)*(y+30)-(z-20)*(z-20) Text2 has spaces a1Text3
Text1 has spaces (x+30)*(x+30)-(y+20)*(y+20)-(z-30)*(z-30) Text2 has spaces a2Text3
Text1 has spaces (x-0)*(x-0)-(y+10)*(y+10)-(z-40)*(z-40) Text2 has spaces a3Text3
Text1 has spaces (x-30)*(x-30)-(y-0)*(y-0)-(z-50)*(z-50) Text2 has spaces a4Text3
Text1 has spaces (x-60)*(x-60)-(y-10)*(y-10)-(z-60)*(z-60) Text2 has spaces a5Text3
```

Just be aware that a "glue" object is returned. You can turn it into type "character" using `unclass` or `as.character`.